# Link is not clickable in IE7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have some basic hyperlinks (they're tags dynamically generated by Wordpress).

Here's the code that generates them:

```
<p><?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?></p>
```

Everything works in all modern browsers (including IE8). However, in IE7, it looks the same, the link is THERE, with all of the properties **EXCEPT** the hyperlink functionality...

Any idea why?

Comment: This has little to do with the underlying PHP code. What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Most likely your link is being overlapped by another element or you're seeing an opacity filter bug (IE6/7 will sometimes make links unclickable when they're in an element with .png or alpha opacity applied to it).

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the confusion. 
All of you are correct. There is nothing wrong with the php tag that generates those links. I think what Thomas is saying makes the most sense. It's probably some element that's positioned on top of it. I'll copy/paste the generated HTML into here. Maybe we can work together to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed the bug, but I'd still like someone who could possibly explain why this fixed made it work.

What I did was the following.

I wrapped the generated anchor links within a div with class 'tags'
Then, in a specific IE7 CSS stylesheet, I gave those links the following styles:

```
.tags a { zoom: 1; }
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of the IE html rendering engine: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Comment: I feel like it's probably the hasLayout bug, rearing it's ugly face again :) http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in WordPress 3.0.1 and found no problem. You may want to install IE Developer Toolbar and check the tags.